# How do I enable SSL encryption from an iOS device to a parse server?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl, parse-server

I have SSL enabled on port 443 of an AWS load balancer connecting to a Parse Server running on Elastic Beanstalk.  How do I enable SSL for the iOS to Parse Server connection?
Can I just enable SSL on the load balancer on port 1337 and forward to the parse server?
Do I have to use a port other than 1337 for the Parse Server SSL?
Are there any special settings in the Parse iOS api that need to change?
Are there any special settings in the Parse Server that need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `parse-server` server is accessible  on `https://yourdomain.com/parse/` then there is nothing more you need to do server side. If not just make sure you pass https in your `serverURL` and `publicServerURL`

Then on the client side you can initialize with the `https:`

Swift 3 Example:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = PARSE_APP_KEY
            $0.clientKey = PARSE_CLIENT_KEY
            $0.server = "https://yourdomain.com/parse/"
            $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true

        }
```

Comment: Then what is port 1337 used for?  Does that port also need SSL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something else as a proxy, for example using node.js, nginx, apache, etc. asimple and extremely clear guide i've used is here: [Guide to Building your own Parse Server](https://medium.com/@dmathewwws/guide-to-building-your-own-parse-server-aad6568b743d)

We are advised not to expose parse-server directly to the internet.

Comment: that particular guide is very useful. i am having problems having parse-dashboard via the proxy.